# Relation between light absortion and molecule structure

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose energy levels of hydrogen (molecule or atom) have an energy difference $\Delta E$. If we illuminate that molecule with light of frequency $\nu$, being energy of light ($h\nu$) bigger than $\Delta E$. Will the molecule absorb light? If not, why not? (I suppose if not there must be a fact, like some spectrum, and a theory which explain it).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your question very simply as I don't want to go to deep into quantum mechanics (that I don't fully handle).

At the beginning of the 19th century, was introduced the idea that light wasn't a continuous flow of energy but rather discrete paquets of light called quanta or photon. 
Let's compare these quantas to integers. As light can only exist in the form of these "integers", saying an atom only absorbs a portion of this light, by the laws of the conservation of energy means that the leftovers of light might not be an "integer", which is by definition impossible.

This idea of categorical "yes or no" with no in between, is very common in quantum mechanics and you also find it in the quantum interpretation of a light beam passing through a polarizer. The classical interpretation is to say that only a part of light's energy passes through (following Malus' law), but in quantum physics this would mean that you won't have an "integer" on the other side of the polarizer, which is impossible. The light particle either passes through or not. Similarly, in your atom, the photon is either absorbed or not.

If you want to learn more about the maths behind this in a concrete example, I suggest you watch this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MzRCDLre1b4

I hope my answer helped!